# Call a user-defined function within a new user-defined function in C++

Tags: c++, r, user-defined-functions, rcpp

I would like to run these function in R by sourcing the C++ code into R. I have used `sourceCpp` function in `Rcpp` R package to load the functions from a `*.cpp` file.

However, when I used the function `get_add_terms_lapply`:

```
get_add_terms_lapply(t = 20,gamma=0.5772,Nb=25.13274)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in get_add_terms_lapply(t = time_end, gamma = gamma, Nb = Nb) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

This is the source *.cpp file that I have used:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double get_add_terms(double i, double t, double Nb) {

  int j = i - 3;

  NumericVector x(j);
  double total = 0;

  if( j == 0){
  total = 0;
  }else{

  for(int u = 0; u <= j; u++) {
  int res = pow(u+1, 2.0);
  x[u] = res;
  }

  NumericVector::iterator it;
  for(it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it) {
  total += *it;
  }

  }

  float log_term = pow(log(t - (0.5 + i - 2.0)), (i-1));
  double int_tot = (total / t);

  double exp_term = exp(-int_tot);
  double add_terms = (i * exp_term * log_term) / pow(Nb,(i-1));

return add_terms;

  }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector get_add_terms_lapply(double t, double gamma, double Nb) {


    float term1 = ( 2.0 * log(t - 0.5) + (2.0 * gamma)) / Nb;

    double N;
    if (t == 1 || t == 2) {
    N = 2;
    }else{
    if (t <= 44) {
    N = t;
    }else{
    N = 44;
    }
    }

    NumericVector term_up(N);
    term_up[0] = 0;
    term_up[1] = term1;


    for(double i = 2; i < N; ++i) {
    term_up[i-1] = get_add_terms(i,  t, Nb);
    }
return term_up;
}
```

Beyond the specific example I have here, I would like to know how a previously user-defined function can be used in a new user-defined function in C++.

Comment: how do you call `get_add_terms_lapply` ? What parameter do you pass for `t` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry..I forgot to add also that information. I have now edited the question, including this information.

Comment: When your second function calls `term_up[i-1] = get_add_terms(i,  t, Nb);` in its first iteration, `i` is 2.  That means inside `get_add_terms`, when the first line is `int j = i - 3;`, then `j` evaluates to -1. You then attempt to create a `NumericVector` with the code `NumericVector x(j);` . This means you are trying to create a `NumericVector` of length -1. Hence the error.

Comment: Yes, indeed this was the problem. Just to add on it...this means that the way in which I'm calling functions within functions is correct, right?

Comment: @CafféSospeso as long as you pass it the correct values, then yes. I would add that if you don't need to use `get_add_terms` directly in R, these is no need for the `// [[Rcpp::export]]` above its definition. Your second function will still be able to access the first if they are sourced from the same cpp file.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thanks.